# How do you add a number as a command line argument?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to add 1 number from the command line, and one number as like a default. 
For example: 
When user types in the number 50 the script will add 10 ( as the default number).

```
./script 50
The sum of 50+ 10 is 60.
```

This is what I have so far.

```
echo -n "Please enter a number: " 
read number 
default = 10
sum = $((default + number)) // this line does not seem to work
echo "The sum of $number and 10 is $sum."
```

Do I have the syntax wrong? I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Am I adding the numbers wrong?  Should I use awk instead?

```
let sum = $default + $number
```

Comment: Just to add, instead of `echo`ing and then the usage of `read` directly you can type: `read -p 'Please enter a number: ' yournumber`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces are causing the errors.

If you want user to input the number when he is prompted as "Please enter a number:", you can use your script with some corrections as:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Please enter a number: " 
read number 
default=10
sum=`echo "$number + $default" | bc`
echo "The sum of $number and 10 is $sum."
```

Check:

```
./temp.sh
Please enter a number: 50
The sum of 50 and 10 is 60.
```

If you want the user to input the number as an argument to the script, you can use the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
number="$1"
default=10
sum=`echo "$number + $default" | bc`
echo "The sum of $number and 10 is $sum."
```

Check:

```
./temp.sh 50
The sum of 50 and 10 is 60.
```

Comment: Why bother running bc just to do simple integer arithmetic?

Comment: @PM2Ring   Some day (maybe today), some user will interpret "number" literally. Bash does integers, bc will handle `3.14159`, awk will handle `3.14159e+03`. Depends on what you want the user experience to be.

Answer (score 15):

You should not have a spaces inbetween "default = 10" & "sum = $", also default & number should have $ before them to read from the variables.

The script then works as expected for me, when written like below;

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Please enter a number: " 
read number 
default=10
sum=$(($default + $number))
echo "The sum of $number and 10 is $sum."
```

Comment: Oh I see! I got it now. It was just a spacing issue. I really over thought this. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Note that you **don't** need to use the `$` inside the arithmetic expression. Eg, try this: `num=5;def=10;echo "sum = $((num + def))"`

Answer (score 5):

**This is the fastest way to do what you are asking:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The sum of $1 + 10 is $(($1 + 10))."
```

**Output:**

```
creme@fraiche:~/$ ./script.sh 50
The sum of 50 + 10 is 60.
```

Comment: that could be dangerous - try `./script.sh '((PATH=0)+(ANY_OTHER_VARNAME=[ANY INTEGER]))'`

Comment: @mikeserv Very accurate, however for the exercise I'm not sure if it is a concern. Thank you for your comment regardless.